# Input box text value trick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a solution where I could have an input box that has a value in, and that value cannot be changed, although if a user goes to enter information into that box, they can add say their name along side the value, but the value cannot be deleted.

Here's an example:

```
First Name:
```

If a user clicks on that box they can then enter their first name.

```
First Name: Kate
```

'First Name' cannot be deleted though and if possible not as a value.

I think this is possible but I can imagine it's a very tricky to do. I saw it on a website once but I can't remember where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can use a mask control or at least same principles. The advantage of this approach is that it covers your needs regarding using a text input and it won't confuse users usability thanks to the `_` on the controls which will let users know clearly what can be removed and what cannot.

Here is an example with [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5QWqH/)**

Your **html**

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" value="" tabindex="1" />
```

Your **script**

```
jQuery(function($) {

     $('#txt1').mask('Something:a*****');
     $('#txt1').val('Something:');

   });
```

> **Disclaimer:** Even though I used jQuery Mask plugin I am no saying it will be the right choice for your application or the only choice but I think it can guide or give you ideas on how your problem can be resolved.

Hope it helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/5QWqH/

Comment: How does this work for say if somebody was entering a first and last name?

Comment: @Xiy There is an online demo. I think it is self explanatory

Comment: @Dalorzo From the demo you've posted it doesn't work for "Kate Kate", so full names using spaces.

Comment: @Xiy who said it works with those values. I think you misunderstood the solution.

Comment: @Dalorzo I didn't misunderstand the solution at all. I clearly asked above, "How does this work for say if somebody was entering a first and last name?", so I think you misunderstood my initial question.

Answer (score 3):

Even if there were possible, and I'm sure it is, you should **not** do it.

Whenever you manipulate a control so that is serves a purpose other than the purpose that it was designed to serve, it becomes a usability issue. Simply put, you are going to confuse your users.

Use a `<label>`, or rethink your interface design completely.

Answer (score -1):

Create a background image which contains the text "First name" and apply it to the text box.  Add some padding-left to the box as well.

Note that you should also use a regular label tag for accessibility reasons, but you can hide that using CSS.